# Convincing Neighbors to Train Barking Dogs

Tags: united-states, conflict-aversion, neighbors

Common problem, about 5 months ago I moved into a new house with next door neighbors that have a loud barking dog (actually 2 dogs ones older though not as much of a problem). So here's the breakdown of my situation.

**The Neighbors:**

- Retired couple early 60's they still volunteer most weekdays so it's hard to tell their schedule.
- Husband's nearly deaf so he's almost impossible to communicate w/ and doesn't mind or hear the noise most of the time.
- Wife I believe is the one who's out of the house most of the day.
- They're actually very nice kind of, they're the kind of people who love talking about themselves. The first time I met them they took an hour telling me their entire family history and I said maybe one sentence about myself.
- The take away from this I think is it's hard to talk to them in person and they believe they are very kind and moral people, which I'm sure they are in the grand scheme of things.

**The Dogs:**

- One older and one younger (6ish I'd guess) Beagle.
- Free to go in and out of the house from 9AM to 9PM (later on weekends) via a dog door.
- Love to bark at anything (other dogs, kids, air, trees, nothing) and do so off and on all day with, I'm biased now but the loudest bark I've ever heard.
- The key is this couple loves these dogs as much if not more then their own children. Their house is covered in Beagle decorations, they have a mailbox that says, "I love my Beagle". This means they will not even entertain the idea that their dogs are misbehaving or need any kind of correction in any way.

**Things I've Tried:**

- **After the first month. Wrote them a letter w/ a gift card thanking them for welcoming me into the area, then kind of off hand at the end mentioning the dog barking has been disruptive in case they didn't know I could hear it.**

  - They wrote back not mentioning the dogs possibly being annoying, just gave me the history of the two dogs and themselves but did give me their contact info. No noise change.
- **A few weeks later during a classic barking fit a Saturday afternoon I went over in person to ask if there was anything they could do.**

  - They instantly dismissed my suggestions of professional training or a barking collar. I did tell them I have to wake up a 4AM so they agreed to bring the dogs in at 9AM... They used to let them go out until midnight even on weekdays. So they think they're heroes now that they gave me one request which makes it livable in my home but now I have more of an uphill battle.
- **Called animal control they said they'd go talk to them.**

  - I'm not sure if they were even home when they arrived, I never heard anything after from them.
- **After a frustrating Sunday of listening to barking they were still going at 9PM as I was trying to bed so, I sent them a rambling text offering training suggestions and even offering them money if they get it training.**

  - All I received from the long text was, "Dog door is closed now.".
- **A few weeks later after the dog was still barking at 10PM  I sent a shorter text again saying I'd help in anyway I can to train the dog.**

  - I think they did bring the dog in but no response to that at all.

**Other Things:**

- Spoke to some of the other neighbors they said it makes them crazy to but not much they can do about it and have gotten used to it.
- The other next door neighbor has 3 giant dogs that are very well behaved but don't want to get involved as they have dogs themselves so are not about to get in a fight about dogs.
- Tried one of those ultrasonic devices to train dogs, did not help.
- Tried my HOA but they said nothing they could do it's on animal control.

**Current Plan:**

- Write another letter this time with more concrete facts and suggestions. Including data on how often it is barking and video recordings of what it sounds like on my end (give them a link to a YouTube video). Also with exact suggestions offering to pay for if they agree (trainers around the area, model numbers of barking collars).
- Make polite but passive/aggressive signs to put in my back yard. This I think would just be hilarious maybe not effective.
- Last resort I'll have to file an official complaint with the county, I'm fully aware now of all the animal rules in my city. This would mean we have to go to court (something I've never done and hope to never do) and make enemies of my next door neighbors for the rest of my time here.

Sorry this is so long, basically I'm trying to brainstorm some other things I can try to help persuade someone to change when they can't see what they're doing as an issue. Ideally peacefully but hey it's a problem and there is a solution somewhere it's just a matter of finding the best one.

Comment: We don't do brainstorming on this site. If you have a specific question about interpersonal skills please [edit] your post to reflect it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input guys, I knew that this was off topic as by the end I was kind of stretching for a concrete question. I got home last night to more barking and decided to call animal control again, they said they'll give another warning before I have to file a complaint. Maybe I'll try a couple things after the second warning if it doesn't work. I do like the dog walking idea as I don't think they every walk them.

Answer (score 0):

Placing signs in your yard, although it may give you a giggle, it will be non-productive for a long-term solution.
Court is a last resort, once all other ideas have been exhausted.

Beagles have:

- very high level of excitability
- love people
- great personalities
- wary of strangers (warm to them very quickly)
- really smart
- like routine
- people pleaser
- train quickly
- lots of energy
  So if that energy is not focused correctly they become bored and noisy.

Exercise:

- take them for a walk once or twice a day speed walking, jogging, running
- will significantly decrease the barking within two weeks will
- Not go to the end of the block and back do a routine if
  possible the dogs will train up easily.

Neighbors:

- When you approach them make it casual as if it would be helpful to you.
- Do not tell them that you want to walk the dogs so they will stop barking.
- You should request that you feel more (comfortable, will stick to your 
  routine, etc) if you had an animal to go on your run or walk and you like 
  their dogs was wondering if it would not be to presumptuous could you walk 
  them.